# Moving batch of EmailMessages using EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Is it possible to move list of [EmailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage(v=exchg.80).aspx) through one request to Exchange Web Service?
The only way how to move one message is [EmailMessage.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.move(v=exchg.80).aspx) method:

```
Item item = beforeMessage.Move(WellKnownFolderName.JunkEmail)
```

Is there any possibility for a batch of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MoveItems method eg ExchangeService.MoveItems https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.moveitems(v=exchg.80).aspx which will batch the request. I would be careful around optimising your batch sizes to avoid throttling issues.